# Performance: Double nested subquery unknown column

Tags: mysql

If I do COUNT()/AVG() in the first subquery MySQL process all rows inside the table, because of that reason it is necessary to filter at from all rows with another subquery.

As example if I have 3 rows, but only 1 row has the id which should get count, MySQL process all 3 rows (according to EXPLAIN) and does the where clause after.

If I'm able to select in a double nested sub query this single row and call the count outside it would be a lot better performance wise.

The problem MySQL does not allow using outer values in a second level subquery.

Simple example of my code:

```
SELECT 
    pr.id, pr.catid, ... 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(pra.id)
        FROM (
            SELECT id
            FROM productsrating 
            WHERE pr.id = productid
        ) pra
    ) as ratingcount,  
    ...
FROM 
(
    SELECT id, ...
    FROM products 
    WHERE active = 1

) pr
```

-> Unknown column pr.id

I do also tried to use the COUNT in the main select but it isn't allowed to have multiple values inside a subquery.

Edit: I have an index on productid.

**EDIT2 SOLUTION**:
Sorry at all its working fine with the first single subquery, server problems caused bad behavior.

Comment: replace `pr.id = productid` to `id = productid`

Comment: pr.id is the id from table products, if im using 'id' it takes the id from the table productsrating

Comment: no it can't. How about doing `JOIN`?

Comment: show us your table structure

Comment: @tcadidot0      if i do a simple join and calling avg or count its the same result,

Comment: @M.Hemant       in my example above its table 'products' with column 'id' and table 'productsrating' with the columns 'id, productid', im matching 'products.id = productsrating.productid'

Comment: Why not just join products to products rating to begin with as a left join and then group by the fields in products?  Do you have some sample data  & expected results we could look at to help better understand the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want the count of ratings occurring for an active product. Is this correct?

So; why is a simple left join not working?  The count of PRA should be based on only those products which are active; so index usage should work here.

I'd need to see sample data / expected results to figure out the overall goal here.

```
SELECT PR.*, count(PRA.ID)
FROM products PR
LEFT JOIN productsRating PRA
 on PR.ID = PRA.ProductID
WHERE PR.Active = 1
GROUP BY PR.*
```

> Substitute all fields needed for PR.*

Maybe this... seems like an odd thing to have to do to get the products rating to be filtered before the average/count is done though.

```
SELECT PR.*, count(PRA.ID)
FROM products PR
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM productsRating PRI
           WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM Products P
                         WHERE active = 1 and PRI.ProductID = P.ID)) PRA
 on PR.ID = PRA.ProductID
WHERE PR.Active = 1
GROUP BY PR.*
```

Comment: Earlier i was using join to connect the data, but the problem is COUNT and AVG uses all rows of productsRating even tough they arent connected to an ID from products. Because of this reason i tried to sort out all rows before doing the count.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps using a correlated subquery to first limit in a derived table.  but this seems like a strange thing to have to do.  order of operations says the join should occur first and the count/avg should be based on that join result after the where clause has been applied.  I'm surprised the count/average isn't first filtered by the Join and limiting by the where.  Sounds like a possible mySQL bug if thats really occuring.  Were you using a left/inner when you tried this originally?

Comment: I will add the full query now in the main post. But i will have the same problem with your correlated subquery that i cant access pr.id inside the sub query. As example the max() does work fine just count() and avg makes problems. I added a row with a productid wich does not match any id to products and this one get processed too.

Comment: Hmm im sorry now after restarting the server it looks like the simple subquery is working and filter correct, dont know what happened may the index did not catched in.

Comment: PR isn't getting used in the correlated subquery.  I referenced products (P) and PR) twice so i'ts not going more than 1 level deep each time.  Good to know a reboot cleared things up; bad to not know why though :(

Comment: i accepted your anwser as solution even tough the simple query is enough for my example, but your answer would work in case the subquery wouldnt be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try count with distinct

```
SELECT 
    pr.id, pr.catid, ... 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Distinct productsrating.id)
        FROM productsrating 
        WHERE pr.id = productid
    ) as ratingcount,  
    ...
FROM 
(
    SELECT id, ...
    FROM products 
    WHERE active = 1

) pr
```

Comment: Unluckily still all rows get processed.